# Date formating of DatePicker in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker

I am using below DatePicker in my Vue.js project.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker

My code is like below

```
<script>
  import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';
  export default {
    components: { Datepicker },
        data() {
          return  {
            dateVal : new Date(),
          }
       }
  }
</script>
```

HTML code is like below

```
<tr>
  <td class="ui header">Applied Date</td>
    <td>
       <Datepicker placeholder="Applied Date" v-model="this.dateVal"></Datepicker>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am getting Date `Sat Aug 10 2019 11:08:57 GMT+0600` . But I would like to get Date `08/10/2019`.

Thanks All.

Comment: you can also use moment.js for Date formating of DatePicker

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<Datepicker placeholder="Applied Date" v-model="this.dateVal" format="MM/DD/yyyy"></Datepicker>
```

it is in the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker
although it says

> This is not very robust at all - use at your own risk! Needs a better implementation.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Function formatter

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-datepicker#function-formatter

https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker/issues/692

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      dateVal : moment(this.dateVal).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
    }
  },
  components: {
   vuejsDatepicker
  },
  mounted(){
 console.log(this.dateVal);  
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuejs-datepicker"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>

  <div id="app">
        <td class="ui header">Applied Date</td>
        <td>
           <vuejs-datepicker placeholder="Applied Date" v-model="this.dateVal"></vuejs-datepicker>
        </td>
  </div>
```

you can try like this using moment.js

Answer (score 0):

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    vuejsDatepicker
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <vuejs-datepicker format="MM/dd/yyyy"></vuejs-datepicker>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuejs-datepicker"></script>
```